# Model impact of atmopsheric circulation changes on precipitation dD of a region

Tags: atmosphere, models, precipitation

I'm looking to model the impact of broad scale atmospheric circulation changes on the hydrogen isotope ratio of precipitation for a given region. As an example, what impact does a high pressure system over China have on the hydrogen isotope composition of rainfall in northern Australia? I wondered if there are any open source coupled atmosphere/precipitation isotope models that have been developed for this type of work?